# Unpacking / Decrypting .dat file

Tags: unpacking, decryption

**Problem**

I am trying to decrypt or unpack a .dat file to know its value. here is the file

[download here](https://mega.nz/#!woUXAaiY!LfJgSuW6uZudQjelIWEepc8TmUP2aTrUdyVh0gg4KHc)

When opened in notepad the text would look like these:

```
UOSEDALB        @(                                                                     &
  Ü
8Ïq"Ê¹zd
#ÅÁLŒô¨8\Jõ^ŒMÿf2 #¯N>¶„¼ÌQ^1C”[8¦ 9ÙÞb![ÒyîÜG#Ž¥n¸õ?ïIÐ±áá¾¥™pG’
æ°Üóbûû­vêØ¢2BKˆ—+Õ/v»XT’‚'Ç]|Véé{&î}ÐÃd­6z;¢éÊ¨ÿS÷úm™¼ #“åd„\HŽ    ¢;$‹ hý€t²'ùjÈ&Í—“‡Rö×&Ôoz…ÉL·ûY·roùˆÝÐ]ÄËDyjÕ[òô!+ØZÎ“ž]àFì0Í+]6†i„ŸƒxÉ´„o''
```

I'm looking for a tool to unpack this .dat file, I'm positive it will have xml type of texts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When Googling for "`UOSEDALB`", I saw several tools that claim to be able to unpack this file type. Have you tried them?

Comment: This question needs more details: where does this file come from, what is it's purpose and what have you done so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of details and initiative